# Proof involving Peano axiom

Tags: peano-axioms

> ### Prove that $n \ne n+1 $ for all $ n \in \mathbb N.$

How do I prove this statement using only Peano axioms?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671154/how-to-prove-that-doesnt-exist-a-natural-number-such-that-is-equal-to-it-success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use induction.  Here is a formal proof in Fitch, which has Induction as a built in rule. Note that $s(x)$ is the successor function, i.e. $s(x)=x+1$

[image]